# AVD manager won't detect my HTC Hero phone as Virtual Device

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, android-virtual-device

I need to use my phone as emulator/target/virtual device when I run my application.
I have installed HTC Sync and the USB driver is in order.
I have enabled the USB Debugging in Settings.

What more do I need to do to make Eclipse AVD Manager to detect my phone?
I made it work on anohher coumputer, following the exact same steps I have done now. "Suddenly" it just detected the phone. This makes no sense! *argh*

Help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I did it I never actually installed HTC Sync.I used the AVD Manager to install the USB Driver and followed these [instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)

Comment: What about Mac users ? :-(

Answer (score 10):

Finally - it works!
In Run Configurations -> Target -> Select "Manual" instead of "Automatic", then you have to choose device or emualtor when you run the application. And then I could choose my phone instead of the emulators.

Comment: 'Automatic' on my system always gives preferences to my real device over the virtual device. However, nice to hear that it works for you.

Comment: I second Sara - I could never get the device to pop up, and it wasn't in the Debug As selection.  The only way it shows up in Eclipse for me is to change it to Manual as described above.

Comment: +1 Once I ran it manually once, I could switch it back to Automatic and it would prefer the physical device over the emulator.

Answer (score 6):

HTC Hero (Android 2.1)
eclipse Helios (3.6)
Windows XP SP3

I got this working by doing the following

1. Make sure that your project is set to debuggable in the manifest `android:debuggable="true"`
2. On the Hero make sure that it is set for remote debugging 
   `Menu > Settings > Applications > Development > USB Debugging` 
   (next three steps I got from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html))
3. Install HTC Sync (3.0)
4. Use USBDeview to remove device
5. Plug in device
6. Check device is added by running
   "C:\Program
   Files\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe
   devices" which said the server was
   out of date and automatically killed
   and restarted it and showed my
   device as connected.
7. Also ran this to be safe "C:\Program
   Files\HTC\HTC Sync 3.0\adb.exe
   devices"
8. Then in eclipse click the drop down
   menu on the debug tool bar item >
   Debug Configurations... delete all the existing configurations and close
9. The next time you debug it finds the
   HTC Hero and runs debug on it

Answer (score 2):

A few tips that helped me get my Phone (Incredible 2) recognized:

1. In Run Configurations, make sure target is set to Manual (otherwise
   might default to emulator)
2. Install Phone drivers (from autoplay menu when plugged in), and HTC
   Sync. If 'Debugging Mode' isn't working, my phone will only be
   recognized by HTC sync and eclipse in 'Sync' mode.
3. Check what version of the SDK you are running. My phone hasn't been
   updated to Android 4.0 yet, so I had to download a previous SDK
   version (2.1.3)

Answer (score 1):

I had a simular problem but i had to enable usb debugging on my actual physical phone and it updated the drivers on windows and now it works

Answer (score 0):

Your phone is not a virtual device. Just plug it in, make sure that USB debugging is enabled on the phone and run or debug your application.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have installed the USB driver, there might be a lurking wrong USB registration with Windows. You can use [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) to check the registered drivers and remove all entries for your phone before plugging it in, then choose the driver from the SDK when asked.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem — USB debugging enabled, no problems with drivers, yet device not detected.  I was trying to run an imported project. I created a new Android Sample Project, and was able to run that on device. After that, the imported project also ran on device.