# Eclipse doesn't find my HTC Sensation

Tags: android, eclipse, htc-android

#### I don't have my Sensation any more, so obviously this no longer is a problem for me. I've decided not to delete the question since it might help others with the same problem.

Thanks for all your attempts to help!

---

I'm trying to program apps for my HTC Sensation (ICS, 4.0.3), but I Eclipse doesn't find it.
When I press the Run "[Application Name]"-button I just get the message "No compatible targets were found. Do you wish to a add new android virtual device?", and no devices is shown in the "Android Device Chooser" that is shown.
I tried with my friends Sony Ericsson XPERIA X10 Mini Pro (2.1-update1), and that worked.
I tried with both version 2.1, 2.3.3 and 4.0.3 of the application, but none worked on my Sensation.
I have USB-debugging, Stay Awake, and Allow mock locations activated.
I've been Googleing around for days, but I haven't found a solution. I've tried the following for example (found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236818/android-avd-manager-wont-detect-my-htc-hero-phone-as-virtual-device)):

1. Make sure that your project is set to debuggable in the manifest android:debuggable="true"
2. On the Hero make sure that it is set for remote debugging
   Menu > Settings > Applications > Development > USB Debugging
   (next three steps I got from http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)
3. Install HTC Sync (3.0)
4. Use USBDeview to remove device
5. Plug in device
6. Check device is added by running "C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools\adb.exe devices" which said the server was out of date and automatically killed and restarted it and showed my device as connected.
7. Also ran this to be safe "C:\Program Files\HTC\HTC Sync 3.0\adb.exe devices"
8. Then in eclipse click the drop down menu on the debug tool bar item > Debug Configurations... delete all the existing configurations and close
9. The next time you debug it finds the HTC Hero and runs debug on it

I've tried to "Run Configurations -> Target -> Select 'Manual' instead of 'Automatic'"

I've installed the Google USB Drivers, and my phones drivers via HTC Sync from [HTC.com](http://www.htc.com/www/help/htc-sensation/#download)

*Edit:*
**I've got some more questions:**

- What version of Eclipse am I supposed to use? I started with Classic, but a friend of mine suggested me to use the *Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers*-version instead.
- What connection type, on my phone, am i supposed to use? Charge only? HTC Sync? I assume it's not Disk drive?
- When I try to run a project for the first time after I start the Eclipse it tells me to  `ensure that adb is correctly located at 'D:\Documents\Eclipse\android-sdks\platform-tools\adb.exe' and can be executed`, that is the directory of the file, and if I go there and run it manually it works, or at least I get past that error (and that's when it tells me I have no device connected).

**Some quick info:**

- I'm running Windows 8 (64-bit) Consumer Preview in Boot Camp on my MacBook Pro
- My phone is a HTC Sensation, Android 4.0.3, HTC Sense 3.6
- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, version: Indigo Service Release 2, Build id: 20120216-1857
- adb version: 1.0.29

Comment: When you plug in the device, does it ask you to enable HTC Sync? In the HTC Aria we use we have to select that option, otherwise it doesn't show up.

Comment: Yeah, it does, but I can't get that to work either. My phone tells me to install HTC sync, and my computer tells me that no device is connected. Disk drive works, though.

Comment: Hmm ... it's just the mode, I don't have HTC Sync in my computer (Do they even have a Mac client?), it's just the "mode". The Aria gets stuck "connecting to service" or something like that, but I just hit the back button and everything is peachy.

Comment: Well, I'm using Windows, Windows 8 by the way, the consumer preview. There is a client for Windows. But I'll try in that mode I've been using Charge only, I'm in the buss from school right now, so I'll do it soon.

Comment: Have you solved this problem already?

Comment: No, but as I've written in the top of my question I don't have my Sensation any more.

Answer (score 1):

I have written an answer here : [HTC Sensation XE - debug in eclipse very poor performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708241/htc-sensation-xe-debug-in-eclipse-very-poor-performance/10719116#10719116)

Please check if it works for you!!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I installed the [USB tethering driver](http://www.htc.com/us/support/htc-sensation-4g-tmobile/software-updates) and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

try to connect to the device in cmd with adb shell, if you don't have enter the adb in you $PATH go to Android sdk folder and try it from there.

You also could check if your device is int the Device-Manager in windows, there it sould be under ADB Interface

Maybe also try this go in Eclipse to Run->Run Configurations and set the Target to Manual. Then you should be able to chouse your device

Comment: Thank you for answering so fast!
I'm not sure if I fully understand what you mean with the first one. I went to the directory and managed to run the file in cmd, but I'm not sure what command I'm supposed to use, when I tried `adb shell` I got the response _error: device not found_.
When I connect the phone to my computer one device appears in the device manager: Android Phone, under Other Devices.

Comment: I might add that I'm using the Consumer Preview of Windows 8, but as I wrote it worked with my friends Sony Ericsson.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my HTC Evo. [This article](http://htcevohacks.com/htc-evo-hacks/how-to-install-android-sdk-and-adb-drivers-for-htc-evo-4g/) worked for me, it involves booting your phone into recovery mode while plugged into USB and installing the driver from the device. I realize this is for a different device, but the same approach may work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried that, but my device didn't show up in the device manager.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the Inspire. Install HTC Sync for the USB driver that comes with it, then uninstall it because it will launch when you connect your phone and because it launches its own adb, you'll end up fighting it.
On the phone, enable USB debugging and set the USB connection to Drive. Charge will work too, but Drive is better because the Eclipse Android Devices view will see all the installed software. 
Once that's set up, you should be able to issue 'adb devices' from a command line and see your phone as 'online' It will also compete a little with the eclipse invocations of the client, but that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know did you find solution or not.
I got the same problem as you mentioned exactly.
I tried all the solutions from google searching, but nothing works...

Then I just put the button "Factory data reset" (Setting/Storage), and it works!

So if you still got this problem, maybe you could try this.

Answer (score 0):

I have Windows 8 and an HTC sensation, after many attemps and a lot of research what worked for me was to Install HTC Sync under compatibility mode and Install the Windows 7 version, after doing this my Eclipse detected the device.

Hope it helps.